# How to annotate a specific data point on plotly interactively?

Tags: python, plotly

I am having some graphs like:

[image]

and the annotation can be shown when the mouse fleets the data points.

[image]

How do I annotate the data points with inputs from textbox other than mouse hover?

Thank you.

Comment: How did the provided suggestions work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

[text and annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/)

- assuming as your plot has so many data points you want to annotate specific points, annotations can be used.  Similarly a scatter with `mode="text"`
- have demonstrated adding annotations to a scatter

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

np.random.seed(25)
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "x": np.linspace(0, 5, 200),
        "y": np.random.uniform(2, 3, 200)*np.linspace(0, 5, 200),
        "annotation": np.random.choice([""] + "the quick brown fox".split(" "), 200, p=(.96,.01,.01,.01,.01)),})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y")
# for r in df.loc[df["annotation"].ne("")].iterrows():
#     fig.add_annotation(x=r[1]["x"], y=r[1]["y"],
#             text=r[1]["annotation"],
#             showarrow=True,
#             arrowhead=1)

# user entered comments against y-values...
comments={10.108395063479417: 'Dolore velit.',
 7.616605000900794: 'Quiquia sit.',
 10.600828870137322: 'Labore aliquam.',
 4.687028794632724: 'Neque modi numquam.',
 8.585248086207281: 'Modi ut.',
 9.398706210473875: 'Amet quisquam.',
 2.1464219321464943: 'Modi magnam eius.',
 2.727208788509655: 'Amet tempora neque.',
 4.352987566322104: 'Quaerat numquam.'}

# add user comments against y-values, lookup x-value
for idxval in df.loc[df["y"].isin(comments.keys())].index:
    fig.add_annotation(x=df.loc[idxval, "x"], y=df.loc[idxval,"y"], text=comments[df.loc[idxval,"y"]])
    
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, what if the users can specify a point where y = 10? The users can input their y values through the HTML input tag. Thx.

Comment: I have updated the answer,  it's just a data structure.  Have created a dictionary of y-values and comments that could have been user entered.  Have not updated image as answer really is no different,  it's just how you want to represent which points you want to add annotations against.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're asking for two different things in the title and the body of the question. You can annotate whatever you'd like with [Text and Annotations in Python](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/). But you're also asking how to do so *interactively*. And for that I would add another trace with a single point that you could add any information in the hoverinfo and get this (on hover):

[image]

This approach uses a pandas dataframe as source for the hover input.

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': ['row 1', 'row 2'],
                        'Column B': ['row 1', 'row 2']})

fig = px.scatter(x=[1,2,3,4], y = [1,2,3,4])
txt = '<br>'.join(f"{'<b>' + key + '</b>'}: {', '.join(d)}" for key, d in df.to_dict('list').items())
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[3], y=[3],
                          marker = dict(size = 12),
                          hovertext = txt,
                          hoverinfo="text",
                          name = 'interactive hoverinfo'
                          ))
fig.show()
```